# ios back button from a tab bar view controller

Tags: ios

this is probably a very simple solution, i am writing an app for iphone that helps people manage their medication for fibromalyosa (i spelt that wrong i think....)

the first view controller of the app is a main menu (which is another problem for another question about collection views)

the menu is embedded in a navigation view controller with the navigation bar hidden to stop the menu looking squashed

the first item of the menu pushes a tab bar view controller with 3 tabs in it (each tab has a view controller)

so here's my question:

how do i implement a back button on all 3 tabs that will send the user back to the main menu?

Answer (score 1):

From you controllers inside the tabs you can call `popViewControllerAnimated:`:

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

This would get the`UINavigationController` that the `UITabBarController` is in.

Comment: i will give that a go, where would i put that line of code though? i can't seem to get a navigation bar to appear along the top of the controllers in the tabs. i also can't place one in on the storyboard editor

Comment: To test if this solution work put a `UIButton` in one of the controllers and put this code in the button's action. Also I'd say you have a lot more questions that the one about going back a search on Google (and here) for using `UINavigationController` inside `UITabBarController` and you will find how to to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[tabController.view removeFromSuperview];

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```